# Octave contourf how to specify the yticks?

Tags: matlab, octave, contour

I have some data to plot its contour. The range of y values is from 0 to 24, but when I use this command:

```
axis ([3.12,14.88,0,24]);
[cc, hc] = contourf(x,y,z,[-1:0.1:1]);
```

however, in the resulting figure the y ranges from 0 to 25: [image]

and the values of x and y are as follows:

```
x =

 Columns 1 through 17:

    3.1200    3.3600    3.6000    3.8400    4.0800    4.3200    4.5600    4.8000    5.0400    5.2800    5.5200    5.7600    6.0000    6.2400    6.4800    6.7200    6.9600

 Columns 18 through 34:

    7.2000    7.4400    7.6800    7.9200    8.1600    8.4000    8.6400    8.8800    9.1200    9.3600    9.6000    9.8400   10.0800   10.3200   10.5600   10.8000   11.0400

 Columns 35 through 50:

   11.2800   11.5200   11.7600   12.0000   12.2400   12.4800   12.7200   12.9600   13.2000   13.4400   13.6800   13.9200   14.1600   14.4000   14.6400   14.8800

y =

    0    4    8   12   16   20   24
```

So what is the problem. I need a plot of y with the same yticks as the above y values.

Comment: Try inverting the order of application of commands: `[cc, hc] = contourf(x,y,z,[-1:0.1:1]);axis ([3.12,14.88,0,24]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a page from Mathworks that discusses customizing tick spacing on an axis:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HXQ/

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if you want the tick marks to appear on 0,4 ..., 24, then the following snippet from the link above should help:

% Set XTick so that only the integer values that range from 0.5 - 12.5 are used

set(gca,'XTick',[1:12])

Comment: Thanks, XTick fixed the tick marks. and Xlim fixed the range from 0:24